# How do I show BERT classification metrics result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, bert-language-model

I am currently learning how to use BERT classification. One of the tutorials that I followed is this one:  https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-multi-class-text-classification-with-bert-transformer-and-keras-c6355eccb63a

the author showed the classification metrics (as shown in the pic), but they didn't include the codes.
How do I create these metrics?

**Classification metrics by the author**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This table is certainly made with sklearn [`classification_report` function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html).

The classes names can be displayed using the `target_names` parameter.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
in `classification_report()`, I need to input `y_true` and `y_pred`. I found that `y_pred` is obtained by using `model.predict(test_x)`. But when I ran the code, it returns an error: `ValueError: Unsupported value type BatchEncoding returned by IteratorSpec._serialize`

Later, I tried converting `test_x` from batch into a list, but then I got an error again:
`ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)`

Trying to convert it again using `asarray()` and inserting it in `model.predict()`  returns the same error.

Comment: @KuugyR you should ask a new question about this (provide your code so that people can see where the problem comes from). Note that you can also ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will ask the question there.